# Async form validation using custom validity

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, validation

I want to let users only submit the form, when the user does not exist already. For that I built a little rest api to check if the typed in user already exists on input blur or form submit. This works

The trickiest part is about setting the custom validity. I want to use native form validation and error handling as much as possible. So I dynamically set and unset the pattern attribute.

**Problem 1:** The message of the invalid input is not displayed when submitting the form by pressing enter (Can I manually trigger the form to display the validity message?)

**Problem 2:** When entering an invalid name, submit and then enter a valid name and submit again, the validation error message appears shortly, then disappears. (Since preventDefault has to be called synchronously, should I re-submit the form when the input is valid and remove the eventlistener for submit, so the form gets submit?

I prepared a little codepen to share with you:
https://codepen.io/MartinMuzatko/pen/BdWmBg?editors=1010

This is the code concerning my problems:

```
usernameInput.addEventListener('blur', async (e)=>{
    let isValid = await isUserValid(e.target)
    console.log(isValid)
})

form.addEventListener('submit', async (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    let isValid = await isUserValid(usernameInput)
    console.log(isValid)
})
```

Thank you in advance!

Best,
Martin

Answer (score 1):

You can use javasript `checkValidity()` to trigger validate.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', async (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    e.target.checkValidity(); //this check
    let isValid = await isUserValid(usernameInput)
    console.log(isValid)
})
```

Comment: Thank you. `isUserValid` does asynchronously check the users validity, so I don't know if the user is valid until I performed that check (but then I know, so I don't need `checkValidity` anymore). `checkValidity` however does only return true or false, it does not let the validity message appear. I just found out that `reportValidity()` does also show the validity message.

Comment: So what do you want to fix other than this ?

Comment: Please see for yourself: https://codepen.io/MartinMuzatko/pen/eEvyYK?editors=1010 and https://media.giphy.com/media/l41K48Jb6rbT9SxSE/giphy.gif
The validity is delayed, correct values can't be submitted - because the validation check is delayed and the submit event is not fired when the input is invalid.

Comment: Also, if I blur the input element and then want to submit, I can't, because I call `preventDefault`. So I have to remove the form event handler when the value is correct?

Comment: @MartinMuzatkoK15tSoftware I think that you want to use keypress event to check everytime that user press a key to check validity

Comment: So if I read the spec correctly, If I press ENTER on an input, no submit event is fired for the form, if one of the elements are invalid. However, if I click the submit button, the submit event is fired, no matter if one more more elements are invalid. So I need to do extra workarounds to this problem. Thank you

Comment: Yes but you can leave onsubmit event check so even when button is clicked you will validate input

Comment: Alright. I made the async validity check on `input`. It almost works as expected. There are a few remaining issues: When I change from invalid to valid and submit before the check is done (via ENTER) then it will not submit the form (since no submit is fired) https://codepen.io/MartinMuzatko/pen/ZJejGB?editors=1010

Comment: It looks good for me it works but i think that it depends on network conditions